# CSS Animated Underline

Tags: html, css, animation

Looking to create an effect on links whereby a border bottom animates upon hover. Found a jfiddle on stackoverflow but having a slightly different effect than expected.

The animation works but is not a smooth animation. Also, the border-bottom is appearing wider than the link itself, rather than just underlining the text.

Am i missing something in my code?

NavBar Links HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
         <li><a href="work.html">WORK</a></li>
         <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-navbar ul li a,
#main-navbar ul li a:visited {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}

#main-navbar ul li a:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: #16b2d9 3px solid;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}
```

Comment: Here is the current code fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6rp12c4f/ to make the border thinner, reduce the border bottom and the padding bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
#main-navbar ul li a,
#main-navbar ul li a:visited {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: transparent 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  line-height:10px;
}
#main-navbar ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: #16b2d9 1px solid;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}


body {
  background: black;  /* for testing purpose */
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="work.html">WORK</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://blog.jasonscott.me.uk">BLOG</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted! Thank you! Only part would be the border-bottom itself extends over the size of the text, rather than just underlining the text. Any advice?

Comment: @Jason updated my answer. You can use line-height to change the position of the border...

Comment: Accepted the answer as it fixed what i wanted initially but the line still overlaps the length of the text, rather than just the size of the text. Line-height pushed the text and the line up but not reduce the length? Any ideas? Otherwise, thanks for solving my initial problem! :D

Comment: @Jason Do you need the size of the line to be the same for all links? If that's it you can set one width for all links. If not, can you explain or show more clearer?

Comment: Ideally, i want the line to be the length of the text itself, so depending on how long the 'word' was, would be dependant on the length of the line?

Comment: I understand, currently the length of the line follows the length of the word. So for example, the line for About starts from the beginning of under A to the end of T.

Comment: Are you experiencing otherwise? May I know your what's your browser and its version?

Comment: Currently it extends over so the line is a larger length of the word, but yes, i want it to start from the beginning of A and end at T.

Comment: I just tested on Mac Safari 8 and it shows the same result. If you can show it with a picture what you're trying to modify I will help you quickly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73799/discussion-between-jason-and-nima).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#main-navbar ul li a,
#main-navbar ul li a:visited {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 3px;

    margin-right: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}

#main-navbar ul li a:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    width: inherit;
    border-bottom: #16b2d9 3px solid;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}
```